How to focus on drag shadow view when talkback on？
I'm using custom DragShadowBuilder for drag and drop。A drag shadow will be created after long click the item when talkback on.
After 1s, i send an accessibility event to the dragshadow. In addition to sending TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED, I also tried TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED and TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER.
After the dragging starts, i can't focus the talkback (green frame) on top of the drag shadow.
binding.item.setOnLongClickListener { view ->
    val data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "")
    val shadowBuilder = CustomDragShadowBuilder(view)
    view?.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0)
    view.postDelayed({
        shadowBuilder.view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED)
    }, 1000)
    false
}

The CustomDragShadowBuilder as follow.
class CustomDragShadowBuilder(view: View) : View.DragShadowBuilder(view) {
    init {
        view.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES
        view.contentDescription = "one two three"
    }
    override fun onDrawShadow(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(view.context.getColor(R.color.custom_drag_shadow_color))
        view.draw(canvas)
    }
    override fun onProvideShadowMetrics(outShadowSize: Point, outShadowTouchPoint: Point) {
        val width = view.width
        val height = view.height
        outShadowSize.set(width, height)
        outShadowTouchPoint.set(width / 2, height / 2)
    }
}

In addition, i found that i could not find this drag shadow node in my app's Component Tree, and its generation did not seem to have any effect on my app.
I expect that once the dragging starts, the talkback (green frame) will be focused on the drag shadow.

[addition a note]
I noticed a sentence in the Android documentation. I'm guessing that the drag shadow is created by the system level.

The system calls back to your app to get a drag shadow. and show it to users during drag-and-drop process.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/drag-drop#AboutDragging
In addition, Drag&Drop supports multiple windows.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/drag-drop/multi-window
If the drag shadow is created by the app level, it is difficult to drag into other app windows, so I think it makes more reasonable for the drag shadow to be created by the system level.
Unfortunately, here are the conclusions of my investigation:
There may be no way to send talkback focus events to the system-level-created view in the app leve.
I hope that can help more developers. If you have better suggestions, please leave a message to discuss.
